# UVA Java runtime error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am a new learner. Why uva show runtime error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a, b, c, i, n;

        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how many test");
        n = d.nextInt();

        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the value of a\n");
            a = s.nextInt();

            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the value of b\n");
            b = x.nextInt();

            Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the value of c\n");
            c = z.nextInt();

            if(a>b && a<c || b>a && a>c)
               System.out.println(a);

            if(b>a && b<c || b<a && b>c)
               System.out.println(b);

            if(c>b && c<a || c>a && b>c)
               System.out.println(c);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which question is this for?

Answer (score 0):

Three small suggestions

- It's actually reading n+1 cases, change "<=" to "<" on the for loop.
- No need to instantiate a new Scanner every time you read, remove all
  "new Scanner..." except the first one, and from then on, use that
  one, e.g. d.nextInt() inside the loop.
- Close the scanner after the loop: d.close();